# How to disable rounding off in pandas script

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Why do pandas round my calculation result? The code I'm using is:

```
 df1.loc[((df1['Cost'] == costgroup) &
                             (df1['Version'].isin(df3['Version2'])),
                             'Cost Total')] = ((df1['Market Spend'] / df1['Sum of Impr']) * df1['Impressions']).round(6)    

.......some more code............  


print("\nWriting output..\n")

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('C:\path..\output_2.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    df1.to_excel(writer, index=False)
    writer.save()
```

By default the precision is showing in the end result which is an excel file, having 4 decimal places, but I want it to have 6 decimal places. I used `.round(6)` but of no use. Same output.
This is affecting my end result!

Comment: Your question misses the most important line: HOW do you save the results into the file?

Comment: On a side note, `round(6)`, doesn't actually give values with 6 decimal places, 6 is the maximum threshold.

Comment: @ThePyGuy Then how to achieve that??